# How to convert varchar to integer

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to commit some values to database by using a data grid viewer,but when I press my submit button displaying a message that saying

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

but record sucessfully added to the database.

This is my query

```
 "objcon.DoExecute("INSERT INTO OrderItemF VALUES('" & dgOrder.Item("Item No", i).Value & "','" & dgOrder.Item("Item Type", i).Value & "','" & txtOdrNo.Text & "','" & dgOrder.Item("Unit Price", i).Value & "','" & dgOrder.Item("Quantity", i).Value & "','" & dgOrder.Item("Discount", i).Value & "','" & dgOrder.Item("Total Value", i).Value & "')")"
```

I used doexecute method for execute the sql string.In here dgorder is data grid viewer name.In my database table Unitprice,discount,quantity and total value represent data type decimal.tell me how to convert these data grid viewer varchar values into decimal?

Comment: Take a look at your table OrderItemF. Did you see numeric fields? Did you pass a numeric value for that field? I guess no because every value you pass for the INSERT INTO is enclosed in single quotes. Meaning it is a varchar for your db. In the meantime search about parameterized query and why you should use it instead of this long error prone string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying column is numeric you *must not* wrap the value you are passing to it in apostrophes. Likewise if you are filtering on a numeric column the same rule applies.

It is bad practice to create an SQL string in this way, you are better off using parameters. The SqlCommand object has a parameters collection, that is the professional way